# f2py : comment line using .f90 file

Tags: f2py

When using f2py with a .f90 file, does one have to use the flag !f2py instead of Cf2py?
I use the intel fortran compiler and it seems compile to a .pyd file if I use !f2py. If I use Cf2py, it fails.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It doesn't have to do with f2py, if you are using `.f90` the compiler will assume free form, and in free form comments begin only with `!`. In fixed form they begin also with `C`.